# Is there a way to configure color-ranges for PM2 monit?

Tags: pm2

I'm using [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) monitor to track my various services.

One tool is designed to use a lot of memory, and constantly shows as red in Pm2. I don't want this. I want to to only show red above a custom threshold I've configured.

Is this possible?